# Java8 Effectively Final compile time error on non final variable

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to change the boolean variable inside java8 forEach loop to true which is non final. But I'm getting following error : Local variable required defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.

How to resolve this error?

Code :

```
boolean required = false;
```

This is the variable I have created in the function.

Now when I'm trying to change it :

```
   map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println("Key : " + key + " Value : " + value);
        required = true;
    });
```

I'm getting the error : Local variable required defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.

Why this error is arising and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot change the local variable from the body of lambda expression. There are several ways to overcome this:

- In this particular case you can just set `boolean required = !map.isEmpty();` without any lambda expression. If you want to set it based on some condition, you can use the Stream API:

  ```
  boolean required = map.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(entry -> ...);
  ```

  This solution is the most preferred.
- Convert the `required` variable to the field of the enclosing class.
- The most dirty way: declare a one-element array: `boolean[] required = {false};` and set this element instead: `required[0] = true;`

Comment: Something like this : The most dirty way: declare a one-element array: boolean[] required = {false}; and set this element instead: required[0] = true;

I actually want to do but as u said it looks dirty. Is there any other way to change the local variable in lambda expression @tagirValeev

Comment: @Siddharth, there's actually no way to change the local variable. In `boolean[] required` case you don't change the local variable, but change the heap object instead.

Comment: Just to enhance my knowledge can you please explain what do u actually mean by changing head object but not changing the local variable. @tagirValeev

Comment: A slightly less ugly way than the one element array is to use an `AtomicBoolean` instead which can change its value via the `set(boolean)` method.

Comment: Yeah, even encapsulating the Boolean variable inside a class and using it will also work. @dkatzel

Comment: @Siddharth a normal `Boolean` object would not work because you can't change the value of that object and you can't make a `new Boolean()` because the reference must be (effectively) final