# Java how to use stream map to return boolean

Tags: lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to return a boolean for the result.

```
 public boolean status(List<String> myArray) {
      boolean statusOk = false;
      myArray.stream().forEach(item -> {
         helpFunction(item).map ( x -> {
              statusOk = x.status(); // x.status() returns a boolean
              if (x.status()) { 
                  return true;
              } 
              return false;
          });
      });
}
```

It's complaining variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final.
If I assign statusOk, then I couldn't assign inside the loop. How can I return a boolean variable using stream() and map()?

Comment: What's the point of using lambda's here? And why would you use `map()` instead of e.g. `anyMatch()`?

Comment: Look tat this question for how to use lambdas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268784/java8-effectively-final-compile-time-error-on-non-final-variable in such situations. Possible Duplicate.

Comment: For that matter what's wrong with making the inner lambda be `x::status` or whatever the proper notation is?

Comment: What is `helpFunction`? What does it return? It's not clear at all what you are trying to do

Answer (score 51):

you are using the stream wrong...

you dont need to do a foreach on the stream, invoke the [anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) instead

```
public boolean status(List<String> myArray) {
      return myArray.stream().anyMatch(item -> here the logic related to x.status());
}
```

Comment: quite a saver! thanks man

Comment: It should be mentioned that anyMatch() uses short-circuit evaluation: it will stop processing items the first time the predicate evaluates to true. So this solution only works properly if x.status() is side effect-free. If you need to invoke x.status() on each x in the collection, you can use `myArray.stream().map(predicate).toSet().contains(true)` instead.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like `helpFunction(item)` returns some instance of some class that has a `boolean status()` method, and you want your method to return `true` if `helpFunction(item).status()` is `true` for any element of your `Stream`.

You can implement this logic with `anyMatch`:

```
public boolean status(List<String> myArray) {
    return myArray.stream()
                  .anyMatch(item -> helpFunction(item).status());
}
```